# calling jquery function outside of scope

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webusercontrol

I'm trying to call a web user control function from the parent page. how can this be done?
I've tried all kinds of ways but none have worked.

**Example:**

```
$('#<%=r1.FindControl("userControl1").ClientID %>').DoSomething();
```

Comment: can you share your user control code? and are you trying to call a server side method from Jquery?

Comment: function DoSomething() { alert('ABC');}

Comment: why do u need to call it using the `control id`?? is it inside an `iframe`?

Comment: because I'm calling the function from the parent page

Comment: can you share the structure of your parent and child page? I am assuming you're referring `Master Page` as parent? if that is the case then both the `master` and the `content page` are the same page. we need more info to help you.

Comment: no it's just a regular page that contains the user control. I just need an example- the simplest one... of how can I call a certain function(that prints 'abc') - how can I call this function from outside the page?

Comment: then you can just call `DoSomething()` without the `controlID`

Comment: did it work @VivianeAbitbol?

Comment: no it didn't sadly...

Comment: Sushil , I wanted you to be the first one to know: It worked! the problem was that the function I wanted to call outside the page was in the $(document).ready function. once I cut and pasted the function outside of the scope it worked! would you recommend that in the future I write all of my functions outside the $(document).ready function?

Comment: Good work @VivianeAbitbol. if all your functions are called from within the `document.ready()` function then its good to keep them inside, if they're called from outside then its better to keep them outside as they won't be available outside scope. an advantage of putting the functions inside `document.ready()` is that it won't pollute the global namespace.

Comment: thanks for all the help :)

Comment: you're most welcome @VivianeAbitbol. actually you should be thanking yourself cuz u did it urself. so Thank you for solving it without taking any help. :)